# Eventos keyup (DOM)

Tags: javascript

El objetivo es que al escribir algo en el input, se escriba también en el párrafo mediante onkeyUp. No obstante no funciona

```js
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar() {
  var titulo = document.getElementById('texto').value;
  titulo.addEventListener('onKeyUp', nuevotitulo, false);
}

function nuevotitulo(e) {
  document.getElementById('textonuevo').innerHTML = titulo;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="texto">
  <br>
  <p id="textonuevo">
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En primer lugar el evento debes atacharlo al `input` no al `value` del `input`

En segundo lugar el evento se llama `keyup` no `onKeyUp`

```js
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar() {
  document.getElementById('texto').addEventListener('keyup', nuevotitulo, false);
}

function nuevotitulo() {
  document.getElementById('textonuevo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('texto').value;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="texto">
  <br>
  <p id="textonuevo">
  </p>
</body>
```